# What is GetSetDescriptorType in Python?

Tags: python

I was looking at types.py to understand the built-in types and I came across this GetSetDescriptorType.  From the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/types.html):

> types.GetSetDescriptorType
>
> > The type of objects defined in extension modules with PyGetSetDef,
> >     such as FrameType.f_locals or array.array.typecode. This type is used
> >     as descriptor for object attributes; it has the same purpose as the
> >     property type, but for classes defined in extension modules

I do understand the property type, but could not wrap my mind around this. Can some one who understands this throw some light ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write a Python module using C, you define new types using a C API. This API has a lot of functions and structs to specify all the behavior of the new type.

One way to specify properties of a type using the C API is to define an array of `PyGetSetDef` structs:

```
static PyGetSetDef my_props[] = { /*... */ }
```

And then use the array in the initialization of the type (see [this example](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html) for details).

Then, in Python, when you use `MyType.my_property` you have a value of `types.GetSetDescriptorType`, that is used to resolve the actual value of the property when you write `my_obj.my_property`.

As such, this type is an implementation detail, unlikely to be very useful.